# Typing ü on a pc

Tags: usage, pinyin

So, in case you haven't noticed, not many ASCII keyboards have the German umlaut as a key. This doesn't tend to be too much of a problem, but whenever typing something like 绿色,  I can never seem to find the character for 绿.  Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried `lv`?

Answer (score 1):

Most Chinese pinyin IME use `v` in replace of `ü`, as v is not used in pinyin alphabet.
You have got your answer in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You type "lv4se4" into a HanYu Pinyin IME to generate the ideographs for "lǜsè". If you type both syllables together, the relevant characters should be automatically selected by your IME.